# Ruby regex to weed out certain dots only

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a set of strings:

```
]  .
]  ..
]  .hu
]  ..ha
]  ho.
]  harr..
```

Each line is one string. I want to match anything except the first two. The other can also contain other characters - not only [a-z] like in the example strings.

I tried a lot of variations like:

```
\]\s+([^\.]{1,2}).*$
```

But I just do not get it.

Comment: `.` and `..` – is this a directory listing?

Comment: @Stefan yes, it is

Comment: Smells like an XY-problem.

Comment: @sawa sorry, i tried my best to be clear. luckily the first answer works for me. if i asked for X and got Y, Y was what i needed. :D

Comment: See https://ideone.com/LYqUho

Comment: [Ruby 2.5 introduces Dir.children and Dir.each_child](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/11/21/ruby-2_5-introduces-dir-children-and-dir-each_child.html)

Comment: @Wiktor, a small point: consider rejecting matches rather than selecting non-matches.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, probably a better idea, I just cooked that demo based on the accepted answer without any further thought.

Comment: Why not simple `lines - ["]  .", "]  .."]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
lines = %|]  .
]  ..
]  .hu
]  ..ha
]  ho.
]  harr..|.split($/)

#                             ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
lines.select { |l| l =~ /\].*?(?=[^ \.])/ }
#⇒ ["]  .hu", "]  ..ha", "]  ho.", "]  harr.."]
```

The above means “everything, that is followed by not space and not dot.”

Or, as @WiktorStribiżew suggested in comments:

```
lines.select { |l| l !~ /\A\s*]\s*\.{1,2}\z/ }
```

Comment: works for me. but why does it not match the other strings with a space after the dot?

Comment: Because **The above means “everything, that is followed by not space and not dot.”**

Comment: Probably, `lines.select { |l| l !~ /\A\s*]\s*\.{1,2}\z/ }` is a simpler option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am not sure it’s simpler, but I have the answer updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One can use two negative lookaheads, one for each of the strings that must not be matched.

```
r = /\A(?!\]  \.\z)(?!\]  \.\.\z)/
```

[image]

```
arr =<<~END.split("\n")
]  .
]  ..
]  .hu
]  ..ha
]  ho.
]  harr..
END
```

```
arr.each { |s| puts "%-10s: %s" % [s, s.match?(r)] }
]  .      : false
]  ..     : false
]  .hu    : true
]  ..ha   : true
]  ho.    : true
]  harr.. : true
```